# Is Ubuntu MAAS only for servers?

Tags: ubuntu, maas

I'm trying to get my head around using Ubuntu MAAS as a means to deploy clients. All the documentation I see exclusively mentions servers. Can I use the MAAS platform to deploy a regular Ubuntu Desktop OS?

Answer (score 0):

Most MaaS relies on management protocols such as IPMI to remotely power on and off servers.  Some desktops do have remote management in hardware but it uses different protocols.  MaaS could use Intel ME or vPro or AMT, but it seems less common.

It sounds like you want automated installation rather than remote hardware management.  Possibly you want not MaaS but the protocols it is built on top of, such as PXE, kickstart, preseed, and services like SCCM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. For the power configuration, please select `Manual` as the Power type. But as default, no official Ubuntu desktop image is available on the MaaS server. You should create your own with certain tools like Paker, then upload it to the MaaS server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).